# TCP - Difference between congestion window and receive window

Tags: tcp, ip

I try to understand the difference between the congestion window and the receive window.

As I understand it, the receiver window is a buffer where the receiver can get the packets. The same is true for the congestion window which tells us the bounds of the receiver's abilities, the window changes according to lost packets, etc.

What is the difference between them?

Comment: I think this would be a better fit at another SE site, as this isn't a programming question or related to developer tools.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To give a short answer: The receive window is managed by the receiver, who sends out window sizes to the sender.  The window sizes announce the number of bytes still free in the receiver buffer, i.e. the number of bytes the sender can still send without needing an acknowledgement from the receiver.

The congestion window is a sender-imposed window that was implemented to avoid overrunning some routers in the middle of the network path.  The sender, with each segment sent, increases the congestion window slightly, i.e. the sender will allow itself more outstanding sent data.  But if the sender detects packet loss, it will cut the window in half.  The rationale behind this is that the sender assumes that packet loss has occurred because of a buffer overflow somewhere (which is almost always true), so the sender wants to keep less data "in flight" to avoid further packet loss in the future.

For more, start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-start

Comment: It will also benefit to know, that any point in time the sender will choose min{congestion-window,receiver-window} to maintain a sliding window size. Which is the number of bytes that are allowed to transmit.

Comment: @cxxl  "" the number of bytes the sender can still send without needing an acknowledgement from the receiver.""---- why sender doesn't need an acknowledgment from receiver don't understand? If sender send the data it must wait for acknowledgment from receiver , but you are saying sender doesn't need an acknowledgment?

Comment: The sender doesn't need an acknowledgement for sending data until the receiver window size is used up. Then it can send to more. This is a feature to ensure a large amount of data to be "in flight" at any given time. Of course, the receiver will have to acknowledge the reception at some time, thus freeing parts or all of the receiver window. These are two interwoven features: high transfer rates and receive acknowledgements.

Answer (score -1):

Initially, CongWindow is set equal to one packet. It then sends the first packet into the network and waits for an acknowledgment. If the acknowledgment for this packet arrives before the timer runs out, the sender increases CongWindow by one packet and sends out two packets. Once all of these packets are acknowledged before their timeouts, CongWindow is increased by two—one for each of the acknowledged segments. Now the size of CongWindow is four packets, and thus, the sender transmits four packets. Such an exponential increase continues as long as the size of CongWindow is below the threshold and acknowledgments are received before their corresponding timeouts expire.One important difference is that CongWindow changes in size but receive window size is always constant.

Comment: Receive window size changes every time data is added to or removed from the socket receive buffer.

Comment: Are you ever going to fix your answer? Five years now.